# Sorting data in Angular js with multiple columns

Tags: angularjs, sorting

Please follow this 
  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rFdsKYSa6Evrlv7jn90q?p=preview)

Issue: I'm trying to `sort` data according to age (`ASC` or `DESC`) but I want Name to remain in ascending order i.e 
if age is ASC (Age: 10) is at top and name start with Raman but it should start with Aman, Baman, John, Raman.

Answer (score 0):

Do create an array of selected order by columns & apply it over `ng-repeat` with `orderBy` filter.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy : ['name', 'age']">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

---

Instead of `['name', 'age']` you can just pass scope variable name that will have array of various selected column for sorting.

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy : sorting">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BskiLgJvX4XNZWEl0xgC?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for quick reply, but its not the solution I was looking for. I want to sort by age (ASC and DESC) and name should always be in asc

Comment: So that so simple...use '+name' when you want ascending sorting.. And use '-name' for descending sort..keep age as is will by default do ascending sorting